# Suppose Y is distributed uniformly in the open interval $(1,6)$. The probability that the polynomial $3x^2 + 6xY + 3Y + 6$ has only real roots is

Tags: probability, functions

I was looking at the solution of this question and it goes as follows :

Polynomial $3x^{2} + 6xY + 3Y + 6$ has only real roots

Therefore,

$$b^2 – 4ax ≥ 0$$

$$(6Y)^2 – 4(3) (3Y+ 6) ≥ 0$$

$$Y^2 – Y + 2 ≥ 0$$

$$Y ∈ (–∞, – 1] ∩ [2, ∞)$$

$$⇒ Y ∈ [2, 6)$$

What I cannot understand is how $Y ∈ (–∞, – 1] ∩ [2, ∞)$, is it not defined for $0$ and $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y^2-Y+2\ge 0 \implies (Y-2)(Y+1) \ge 0 \tag1$

so you should check how the signs of $(Y-2)$ and $(Y+1)$ changes for different values of $Y$. Since $$Y\in (1,6) \implies Y+1>0 \tag2$$ $(2)$ combined with $(1)$ implies that $Y\ge 2$, so $Y-2\ge 0 \implies Y\ge 2$ and since $Y$ is defined in $(1,6)$, $Y\lt 6$, so we have $Y\in [2,6)$.

**Note for doubt:** for the product $(Y-2)(Y+1)$ to be $\ge 0$, both of them have to be of the same sign, or at least one of them $0$. If both are non-positive, then $$Y-2\le 0, Y+1\le 0 \implies Y\le 2, Y\le -1 \implies Y\le -1$$ where we have taken the intersection of the two conditions, $Y\le 2, Y\le -1$, since $Y\le 2$ is already satisfied if  $Y\le -1$ but not the other way round, so $Y\le -1$ which gives the interval $(-\infty,-1]$.

Similarly if both are non-negative, you get by a similar argument $Y\in [2,\infty)$.

Of course, since $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $(1,6)$, $Y$ does not take values $0,1$ which are outside that interval.